Sheaf $\mathscr{F}_S$ for which $\mathscr{F}_S(U)$ consists of holomorphic sections that vanish on $S \cap U$ isomorphic to $\mathscr{O}(L^*_Y)$
Let $M$ be a complex manifold and $Y \subset M$ a closed hypersurface and $L_Y$ the holomorphic line bundle associated with $Y$. How can I show that the sheaf $\mathscr{F}_Y$ for which $\mathscr{F}_Y(U)$ consists of holomorphic sections that vanish on $Y \cap U$ is isomorphic to the sheaf $\mathscr{O}(L^*_Y)$ of holomorphic sections of the dual bundle $L^*_Y$? I cannot come up with a suitable morphism of sheaves $F: \mathscr{F}_Y \to \mathscr{O}(L^*_Y)$, I think that I have to use the fact that locally $Y$ looks like the zero set of a section $s$ of $L_Y$, but I'm not really sure where to send $$F_U(f)$$ for a section $f$ of $\mathscr{F}_Y(U)$. Any hints for this?

What is $S$? I assume it's just $Y$. In that case, $\mathscr{F}_Y$ is known as the ideal sheaf of $Y$, and the isomorphism $\mathscr{F}_Y\cong\mathcal{O}(-Y)$ is well-documented in e.g. Huybrechts' "Complex Geometry" (see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987624/why-is-the-ideal-sheaf-mathcali-y-equal-to-mathcalo-y-and-not-math )

Is $\mathcal{O}(-Y)$ the same sheaf I'm denoting as $\mathscr{O}(L^*_Y)$? @QuaereVerum

Yes. Typically, one denotes by $\mathcal{O}(D)$ the sheaf associated to a divisor $D$, which is an invertible sheaf (i.e. a line bundle). They form a group under the tensor product, and $D\mapsto\mathcal{O}(D)$ is a group homomorphism. In particular, $\mathcal{O}(-D)$ is the dual of $\mathcal{O}(D)$.
